# A bit number of Color channel of RGB, ARGB and RGBA

Tags: java, colors, rgb, rgba, argb

This is a order of bit number of color channel from wiki
[ARGB and RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)

but there is a different order from another site
[image: Link]

Which one is correct??

How about the order of RBG???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia's picture :

[image: ARGB representation on little-endian architecture]

depicts layout of bytes of 32-bit `ARGB` integer on [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian#Little-endian) architecture.

Whereas picture from your question corresponds to [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian#Big-endian) layout of same `ARGB` integer.

So, the answer is : both pictures are correct, they just account for different architectures in terms of bit addressing in memory.

**What you should care about is**, regardless of endianess,  for `ARGB`, `A` is the most-significant byte of 32-bit value, `R` at the second-most significant, ... and `B` can be found as the least significant Byte.

So you can extract them correctly with corresponding bit-shifting operations regardless on what type of "endian" platform you are.

**Edit**
In fact, the picture from your question seems odd to me, since it displays `A`, `R`, `G`, `B` bytes in reverse order (even addressing them correctly). I recommend you stick to diagram from wikipedia to avid confusion.

Answering your comment : Java's `TYPE_INT_BGR` has reversed encoding of `rgb` colors as compared to `TYPE_INT_RGB` , see [java.awt.image.BufferedImage.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.java#362) :

```
case TYPE_INT_BGR:
         {
             colorModel = new DirectColorModel(24,
                                                   0x000000ff,   // Red
                                                   0x0000ff00,   // Green
                                                   0x00ff0000    // Blue
                                                   );
```

Which one to use depend on your needs, but I would guess you'd be ok with `RGB` and `ARGB`.

Hope that helps

Comment: In Java api, there have two TYPE_INT_BGR and TYPE_INT_RGB. Both of them are different order??

Comment: I updated my answer. Yes, those types have different order. I suggest you stick to `RGB` & `ARGB` as most widelyused